# why guidelines says "avoid async void" rather than saying "don't avoid awaiting on task"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, design-guidelines

Why guidelines says "avoid `async` `void`". I don't know, but I feel guideline should rather say - "`await` `task`". Problem with `async void` is that caller will not know if it need to `await` for completion and control will continue with execution of following statements. I can understand ill effect of this. But even if `async` method returns `task` instead of `void`, caller can still miss to await and get into same issues, right ? Hence the question, why not guideline rather says - *don't avoid awaiting task*

Comment: you can do that , but what if you want to check the task later on, that is and you have given void return than you cannot do that , that is the reason

Comment: @PranayRana : so if I understand correctly, you saying it should be callers responsibility and no such guideline applicable in that case ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal You should still absolutely be avoiding it from the callers perspective as well, because it's very rarely appropriate, but when it *is* appropriate to ignore the results of an asynchronous operation, yes, it is the caller that should be the one making that decision.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - you can check my answer , that can be one logical reason..

Comment: @Servy : I understand that caller might directly wait on task rather than awaiting for completion - but does not that defeated whole purpose of calling async operation ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal What does that have to do with my comment?  I didn't say anything about synchronous waits.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - one reason could be API exposed used by multiple project ..and in the other project they like to wait

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do that, i.e., you can do void or do not wait for `task` to complete at all.

But there mayt be a scenario where you developed an `API` which is used by multiple `projects`, and some of the project which use your method want to wait to complete call although the method is going to returning nothing just for check or for doing work after method get completed.

In that senario its helpful and that is the reason you must return `Task` not `void`. It helps the others who are using your method.

That is one of the logic reason apart form what you have given in question.

Comment: this point makes sense _But imagine a scenario where you developed API which is used by multiple projects, and some of the project which use your method want to wait to complete call_ thanks!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - welcome...there is always a reason behind putting guidelines.... :)

Comment: Agree. But if other projects calling wait on async operation rather than waiting, then whole point of calling async operation is defeacted, isn't ?

Comment: not directly related to this post, but  when i see console app..my root main method have to wait the result, no matter how much async/await paradigm i have in call stack. This also i feel kind of bit uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2):

You don't always *want* to prevent the rest of the method from executing until that operation has finished.  Sometimes you have some things you can do before it finishes, so you want to await it later, maybe that one caller happens to just not need the results, so it can ignore it safely, etc.  The point is, because the method returns a `Task` it is up to the caller to do with it what they will.  If they want to do something when that task finishes, or know if it has succeeded or failed, they can, and if they don't that's fine to.

When the method is an `async void` method *that is taken out of your hands*.  The caller is put into a position where they *can't* know when the operation has finished, even if they really need to know.  And that's just not a decision that should be made when writing the method.  That method isn't going to know who all is going to call it, and whether or not they'll need to know when/if it has finished, so when writing the method you need to assume that someone *will* want that information.

All of that said firing off an async method and ignoring it entirely should be very rare.  There *are* situations where it's appropriate, but it should be a big red flag anytime you see it.  When it *does* happen though, it should be the *caller* of the method making the decision that they don't care about when that operation finishes, not the author of the method deciding that no one should ever be able to know when it finishes (again, outside of some really exceptional situations).

Comment: one reason could be API exposed used by multiple project ..and  in the other project they like to wait